# What was the relevance of the sentinel passing through Neo in Revolutions

Tags: the-matrix

This question relates to the movie : [Matrix Revolutions](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0242653/)

When Neo and Trinity are on the way to the Machine Mainframe on a ship. Neo uses his mind to destroy the sentinels that attack them.

One of the sentinels is shown to go right past Neo. This is shown in a golden vision. In reality, there is no sentinel that actually enters the ship and physically touches Neo. What is happening here?

Here it is 
[image]

Let me clarify what I'm looking for. I would like to park the idea of matrix with in the matrix idea because that invalidates the whole trilogy. That invalidates any knowledge of how the current world looks like. That also gives rise to infinite possibilities and explanations to what is actually happening in the real, real world.

I would like an answer that uses the in-movie science to explain this.

Comment: You appear to be under the mistaken impression that anything in this movie makes logical sense.

Answer (score 6):

From what I can tell, we're seeing a **wireless attack** on Neo's connection to the machines. The Sentinels, sensing that Neo is interfering with their main function (to prevent ships from approaching the Machine City) launch an attack on whatever allows him to wirelessly connect to them, presumably via his neck-port. The "ghost-Sentinel" is therefore **merely Neo's visual interpretation of that attack.**

Note that the screenplay explicitly states that the effect is that he ***"feels himself disconnect"***:

> Wrestling with it. As its eyes begin to blink, it corkscrews wildly
>   out of control, slamming against the heavy plated glass which
>   shatters, cratering under the Machine's bulk as
>
> We experience what Neo experiences; a meteor of light that blasts
>   through his body--
>
> INT. LOGOS - COCKPIT - NIGHT
>
> Wrenching free his grip from Trinity.
>
> **His arm flails back as he feels himself disconnect, his mind flung
>   loose until** — She snatches hold of him again,
>
> **TRINITY :** *I got you.*
>
> His head swims as he drags himself back from the abyss.

Comment: In the trilogy, when ever they show a vision in the matrix in code, it's someone's vision. Eg: Neo looking at Smith, Merovingian looking at the girl eating the cake. The golden vision is through machine eyes. Again Neo's visions are shown in gold to indicate a machine view. The ghost tentacle scene shows it from where trinity would be sitting. Who exactly is viewing this?

Comment: @Tivep - Neo sees the machines in gold light, not gold code. The (out of universe) symbology is obviously much the same though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say gold light. This scene is a 3rd person view in the gold. A view from where trinity is seated. All the other times its typically first person, through Neo's vision, or at the machine mainframe, the machine's vision. Who exactly is viewing this scene? It's not trinity.

Answer (score 3):

My explanation will take a bit of an intro.

See all the humans that were freed are not complete humans. No humans have holes. Then what are they? Mechanically modified humans. A hybrid where they are mostly human but have a bit of machine in them for ease of being connected to the Matrix.
Now we all see this world differently. Cats and dogs see it all green and eagles look at much sharper images of world, while we humans have a great quality picture with a lot of colours and obviously, the machines, will have their own point of view. The gold coded view is a machine's view.

Neo is also a modified human but also the One. He had no limits in the Matrix. He would have been much more powerful if he had been freed a bit earlier. I see his powers in Matrix would look similar to Lucy's (that stupid sci-fi about brain usage). But well he touched the Source, he had the ultimate data to reload the Matrix, he had a direct connections to the machine mainframe, the exact frequency at which it works, thus in real world, himself being modified human with knowledge about mainframe and signal frequency, he used it in his favour with his mind hole working as an antennae. The gold code view he gained when his human view was switched off. He had it since coming out of the Architect's room but his brain simply preferred the human view (because he is mostly human). When the human view went down, he realised the machine view that all the other machines had. By getting into the Architect's room, he was made aware of his machine side and thus he was more machine then ever. That's why he successfully harnessed all the normal machine powers like sending a signal to self destruct and having the normal machine view as the abilities.

He just started working as an alternate signal carrier sending signal at the same wavelength as the mainframe.

No other blind in the world have the gold view because they haven't touched the Source. Neo however, after doing it unlocked the vision.

Comment: This is a great answer to why he sees in gold. However the question I asked was the golden sentinel passing through Neo is not what Neo sees. It's in 3rd person. Who is then viewing this. What does the sentinel passing through Neo imply.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately I think only the Wachowski's can clearly answer that. They wrote the story and it all comes from their imagination. In all reality, everything else posed by us is simply guess work and speculation. I discovered this page while exploring an answer to your question. The second theory seems more plausible theory in my mind.

Source: http://thematrix101.com/contrib/rev_theories.php

> Gold Code
>
> Submitted by Chris Dorst
>
> First-off, I'm not sure if I believe this theory or not myself, but I thought it was interesting nonetheless. This theory attempts to explain Neo's ability to see the world in gold light after he becomes blind in Revolutions.
>
> Throughout the trilogy, Neo gains more and more abilities. This is not only apparent in the Matrix, but in the real world as well. In the Matrix, Neo flies, stops bullets, and is faster and stronger than everyone else (except Smith). He can do all of these things because he is the One, the "result of the remainder of an unbalanced equation inherent to the programming of the Matrix; the eventuality of an anomaly." Outside of the Matrix, Neo destroys sentinals and can see the world in gold light. The Oracle explains his ability to destroy sentinals by telling him that his power extends back all the way to the Source (the machine mainframe), and that he manifested that power to destroy the sentinals. After Neo becomes blind, he can see the supposed real world in gold light. This ability is never completely explained in the trilogy, which is why there are many theories that try to explain it.
>
> My theory: The gold light that Neo can see in the real world is actually the code of another Matrix, or level of the Matrix. Thus, the world where Zion exists is really part of a Matrix, or a "Real World Matrix."
>
> Gold Code II
>
> Submitted by Rewris
>
> The "Gold Code" is in my opinion is simply the energy force of the machines in 01 (Machine City). That's all it is, the catch about it, the thing to bake your noodle, is why Neo can see it. But then again, I think the answer is quite obvious: Neo is the One. I have read some theories on the One, but I can't agree with them for the simple reason of them denying Neo of the power that everything in the movie conveys him to have or be about. Neo is the One; he can modify the Matrix as he sees fit, to some extent yes, of course he is limited. He can stop bullets in midair but he can't manifest them in out of air. The Matrix is based on rules, it is a simulation of real life, made to be that way so the humans would embrace it and not wake up. So that it will seem all the more "real" and less dream-like. Although a lot of big things may happen, like a man flying on the freeway, it is still small on a certain level.

There you have it, Two theories on why Neo was able to see the "Gold" code. I hope I've helped at least a bit.

Comment: Downvote because the "Matrix within a Matrix" theory is a fan-theory that has been repeatedly debunked.

Comment: @Richard debunked or just denied?  Because otherwise to see as he did after his eyesight was destroyed, Neo would have to be God.

Comment: @Moo - He can only see powered machine elements. The most likely explanation is that his neck-port is wirelessly connecting to them.

Comment: @Moo - Firmly debunked. Unless you assume that all three films are pretty much pointless.

Comment: Another theory I read involved a fact that when Neo destroyed Smith in the first movie, an impression of him was left behind. That impression was then used by the Architect to recreate Smith with the ability to counter Neo and his "Oneness" this residual echo that Neo left is what enabled him to "see" the golden code outside the Matrix in the real world. When Smith absorbed Neo the Architect was again able to balance the equation, destroy Smith and in turn reset the Matrix. This is simply a theory I identify with most.

Comment: @Richard I already consider all three films pretty much pointless with a weak ending, so...  I have never bought the neck-port theory.

Comment: @Moo Also, the question specifically asks for an explanation that does *not* invoke the Matrix within a Matrix theory.

Comment: To add to my last comment, I missed explaining his ability to see the gold code in the real world. Neo is able to see the gold code because of a psychic link to his residual self that still exists with the Matrix. Because the matrix is within the machine world and all machines are therefore likely networked together, it's plausible that Neo is able to see and sense other real world machines that are linked.

Comment: I find theory 1 to be logically sound and well thought out, while theory 2 is just a statement followed by a long ramble that's completely unrelated to it. Much like the films really.

Comment: @Moo, I understand considering the 3rd part a little pointless, but don't you think the first two were brilliant in both concept and execution. When the first Matrix released, not only did we get a brilliant visual treat, it made us question the "reality" of our existence. I thought the movies were very defining in the evolution of the next gen sci-fi  concepts and visual effects.

Comment: @Tivep I consider all three pointless *because* of the weak ending - just the same as BSG, Lost etc.

Comment: While I agree with the first theory myself, I feel I have to downvote since the OP specifically says no MWaM answers.

Comment: @Valorum Just curious, who did "firmly debunk" the matrix within a matrix theory? If they did, at least there has to be an explanation of how a wired interface suddenly became wireless, without any physical modification. If this is supposed to be in the actually real world, it makes zero sense to me.

Comment: @Malcolm - it was debunked with the third film not revealing a new layer of Matrix and seeing the Machines (the Oracle and the Architect) talking among themselves. If they were inside a second level Matrix that would make no sense. Additionally, we learn the history of the (single layer) Matrix in [The Second Renaissance Part II](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/The_Second_Renaissance) and find out that people inside the Matrix can tell when they're inside the Matrix in [Matriculated](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Matriculated) hence why they feel the need to leave.

Comment: @Malcolm - You may find this of interest; http://www.matrixresolutions.com/index.html?page=debunked_matrix_within_matrix - For me, the biggest clue is that the makers wouldn't invalidate their entire film series and make it a pointless game inside Neo's head.

Comment: @Valorum If something isn't revealed, it may still exist. I've watched Animatrix thoroughly before, I didn't see any statements that the matrix is specifically single-layered. Human feelings are unreliable, they know how it feels different in the real world, but what if they are supposed to, so they don't feel that they are still in the matrix? No one can rule that out. I don't feel that the film is invalidated by the matrix within the matrix, all of this is happening with real people regardless, doesn't matter whether the world itself is real. Thanks for the link, I'll check it out.

Comment: The part about the Oracle and the Architect I didn't get.

Comment: @Malcolm - The issue is, if the machines were capable of creating an upper layer of Matrix that wasn't detectable, why wouldn't they use it on the lower level. Why would they need to create a choice-based Matrix at all.

Comment: @Valorum It is detectable. It took a One to free understand that the Matrix is an illusion, and, according to Morpheus, he freed the first people. It took six Ones to find out that there is another layer beyond the first one. Neo just didn't have the time to explore its limits and explain anything to anyone. No one thought there might be the second layer for the same reason people didn't know in the first layer: they can't feel it themselves until they went one layer up and have something to compare with, and no one was there to tell them. To my mind, Wachowskis made it ambiguous on purpose.

Comment: @Malcolm - I strongly doubt that any filmmaker would soil their vision by making a three film series into a dream sequence, but sure, you're welcome to believe whatever you want, even in spite of the evidence.

Comment: @Valorum I've already said that nothing in this theory soils the vision, it only does in your opinion. Also I've explained why the mentioned evidence is not absolutely conclusive. However, there is still no explanation regarding how wired interfaces become fully wireless. The theory is apparently far from "firmly debunked", but I see your point and what you meant.

Comment: @Malcolm - We know from several of the Matrix Comics (*Goliath*, for example) that the Matrix can be transmitted wirelessly

Comment: @Valorum As far as I understand, they are not canon. Unfortunately, I don't know what points they made you refer to, so can't comment on that.

Comment: @Malcolm -The stories selected for the two comics anthologies are (according to the Wachowskis) considered canon. Some of them are a little 'out there', admittedly, and some of them are obviously comedic.

Comment: @Valorum I've just read Goliath, the man was most definitely plugged into the ship, just like in the films. It is explicitly mentioned. Besides, I didn't find any statements by Wachowskis that comics are canon.

Comment: @Malcolm - But the Matrix signal was being broadcast wirelessly.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, from **a ship**. **Not a head**. No one disputes that ships can connect wirelessly. That would be ridiculous since all ships in the films operate that way.